# Azure Stream Analytics - SQL to convert string to float

Tags: sql, azure, types, type-conversion, azure-stream-analytics

What is the easiest way to convert a string to a float in the Azure Stream Analytics job service query? Unfortunately, I'm quite new to SQL, but only need this conversion applied to the CSV data stream.

This is what I get from the Test option on the query page...

```
'DeviceID','Temperature'
'20','30.8'
'20','32.1'
'20','31.5'
'20','28.2'
'20','29.1'
```

...when I use...

```
SELECT *
INTO TempPowerBI
FROM Tempiothub
```

... but in Power BI, the numbers can't be displaced. Instead, the amount of data is counted. So I guess the Stream Analytics query is the best place to convert the data.

Thanks a lot in advance ~

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize `CAST()`. Try This:

```
SELECT DeviceID , CAST( Temperature AS float) as  Temperature
INTO TempPowerBI
FROM Tempiothub
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn834995.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a dynamic way for multiple parameters? E.g. like:
SELECT DeviceID, CAST(* AS float)
INTO TempPowerBI
FROM Tempiothub

 -- Thanks a lot!